# conditional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm trying to code an array that displays a certain set of products depending on the gender of the logged in user.  The arrays not really the problem but the parts where I'm going to have to check the database then create the conditional statement from the results is the main problem i think.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

include"config.php" or die "cannot connect to server";

$gender=$_POST['gender'];



    $qry ="SELECT * FROM server WHERE gender ='$gender'";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);


    $productdetails;
    $productdetails1["Product1"] = "£8";
    $productdetails1["Product2"] = "£6";
    $productdetails1["Product3"] = "£5";
    $productdetails1["Product4"] = "£6";
    $productdetails1["Product5"] = "£4";
    $productdetails2["Product6"] = "£8";
    $productdetails2["Product7"] = "£6";
    $productdetails2["Product8"] = "£5";
    $productdetails2["Product9"] = "£6";
    $productdetails2["Product10"] = "£4";

         if (mysql_num_rows($result) = 1) {
        foreach( $productdetails1 as $key => $value){
            echo "Product: $key, Price: $value <br />";
            }
         }                  
         else {
        foreach( $productdetails2 as $key => $value) {
            echo "Product: $key, Price: $value <br />";
            }
         }
?>
```

Comment: Gender should be sanitized before used in the sql query. This is just asking for injection.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? What is the output you get? With which input? You have to be more specific, just saying "I have a problem with this" is not much to work with. Since we cannot even run the code (we don't have the database) you have to provide more information.

Comment: the exact problem is i get the message "Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in F:\xampp\htdocs\account.php on line 65" when i try to execute the code.

Comment: Your provided code does two things, and does not bound the problem. Having 10 products enumerated is overkill - we'd get the idea with 2-4 products. Further, what are you trying to do with your if/else and foreach statements? Simply print out one array or the other depending on gender?

Comment: And is `account.php` the code you posted? Which is the line 65? *edit:* ah... have a close look at `mysql_num_rows($result)=1`. Googling the error returns many hits btw...

Comment: yeah basicly all i want the code to do is to check the users gender which they entered when registering and then to display the correct array based from that value.

Comment: k so what would i put for the statement then  if, the values ive created for the gender is either 'm' or 'f' ($qry($result) == 'm') ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't use function return value in write context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321522/cant-use-function-return-value-in-write-context)

Comment: @arnie89 - If the database value is either `m` or `f` then, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You if statement is wrong. `=` is an assignment operator, you should use a [comparison operator](http://php.net/operators.comparison) like `==` or `===`

Answer (score 0):

What happens with the current code?

Some tips:
First try echoing $gender, to make sure it is getting through. It is submitted through post, what happens if nothing is being posted? Where is this coming from? You should try to use get instead. This seems like something you'd give someone a link to therefore post doesn't make sense here. You could always have both, and just get post if it exists otherwise use get otherwise default to 'male' or 'female' depending on your audience.

Next, what is your query outputting? It might be empty at this point if gender is not giving anything back. It seems like you are querying for all rows where gender = whatever was passed, but then your if statement is asking was there anything returned? Then all you are doing is going to the arrays, but you shouldn't be doing that you should be outputting what you got from the DB. Assuming you do actually have products in the table called server you should do something like this:

```
$products = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM server WHERE gender ='$gender");

while($product = mysql_fetch_array($products)){
    echo $product['name'] . " " . $product['price']. " " . $product['gender'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

On that note. You should really call your table something else, like product not just "server" unless by server you mean a table filled with instances of waiters or computer hardware.