# Can't use method return value in write context; Not sure where to go from here

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't use function return value in write context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321522/cant-use-function-return-value-in-write-context)

This is my source for the variable.

```
<?php
if ($admin->get_permissions()=3)
echo 'Welcome to the Admin Panel';
else
echo 'Sorry, You do not have access to this page';
?>
```

And the code that I'm actually trying to call with the if statement is:

```
public function get_permissions() {
        $username = $_SESSION['admin_login'];
        global $db;
        $info = $db->get_row("SELECT `permissions` FROM `user` WHERE `username` = '" . $db->escape($username) . "'");
        if(is_object($info))
            return $info->permissions;
        else
            return '';
    }
```

This should be a simple way to call my pages that the user is authorized for by using an else if statement. *Or So I thought*

Answer (score 2):

You need to change

```
$admin->get_permissions()=3
```

to

```
$admin->get_permissions()==3
```

`=` is the assignment operator, and `==` is the equality comparison operator.  The parser is telling you that you can't assign `3` to the result of a function.  It doesn't make any sense to do that.

Comment: Feel free to slap overlooker. *Embarrased*

Answer (score 0):

`=` != `==`

```
if ($admin->get_permissions() == 3)
```